# How to call GCP Data Catalog API from .NET authorizing via a Service Account?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I am trying to call GCP Data Catalog API to do a search. I have created a Service Account in GCP.

Using Google.Cloud.DataCatalog.V1 package from Nuget.

```
DataCatalogClientBuilder dcb = new DataCatalogClientBuilder();

dcb.CredentialsPath =  "json.json";

DataCatalogClient dataCatalogClient = dcb.Build();

SearchCatalogRequest scr = new SearchCatalogRequest();
scr.Query = "vbeln";
PagedAsyncEnumerable < SearchCatalogResponse, SearchCatalogResult >  sdjh = 
dataCatalogClient.SearchCatalogAsync(scr);
```

a) The SearchCatalog is not returning the result
b) I am not able to pass scope (defining project, org)

Is there any mistake.

Running on .NET Framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to the problem.

Steps followed were as per the OAuth2 for a Service Account
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

It is a 3 step process -:

a) Create a JWT token using RS256 algorithm with claims/ payload as -:

> ```
>      { "iss", "<service-account>@<project-Id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"},
>      { "scope", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" },
>      { "aud", "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token" },
>      { "iat", iat},
>      { "exp", exp}
> ```

```
var iat = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
var exp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60).ToUnixTimeSeconds(); \\ 60 mins usage
```

*Refer end of this answer for complete code for creating a RS256 JWT token from .NET

b) Call Token API https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

**Request**

> grant_type = urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
> assertion  = JWT generated in Step 1

**Response**

```
{
    "access_token": "******************************************************",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

This access_token will be used to call the actual API, and is valid for 1 hour.

c) Calling the Data Catalog Search API : https://datacatalog.googleapis.com/v1/catalog:search

**Method** : Post

**Request** :

> ```
>   Authorization Type : Bearer Token
>   Token Value        : access_token received in Step b
> ```

```
Body : 

{
  "scope": {
    "includeProjectIds": [
           "project-id1"
           "project-id2"
    ],
    "includeOrgIds": [
      "orgid"  
    ]
  },
  "query": "tag:project-id1.test_template1.owner:ZZZZZ OR COLUMN:VBELN"  -- Search Tag, can be fetched from [Try It link][4] or [Search Guide][4]
}
```

**Response** :

The catalog search output.

Sample :
[image]

*Code to create JWT token from .NET to be passed to GCP OAuth Token API -:

```
using JWT;
using JWT.Algorithms;
using JWT.Serializers;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace GCP
{
    class JWTTokenGenerationForGCPOAuthTokenAPI
    {


        public static string GenerateJWTToken()
        {
            var rsaParams = ReadAsymmetricKeyParameter();
            var encoder = GetRS256JWTEncoder(rsaParams);
            var iat = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
            var exp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60).ToUnixTimeSeconds();

            // create the payload according to your need 
            // iss is the Service Account Email ID
            var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "iss",   "<service-account>@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"},
                { "scope", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" },
                { "aud",   "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token" },
                { "exp",    exp},
                { "iat",    iat}
            };
            //Final token
            var token = encoder.Encode(payload, new byte[0]);

            return token;
        }

        private static IJwtEncoder GetRS256JWTEncoder(RSAParameters rsaParams)
        {
            var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            csp.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
            var algorithm = new RS256Algorithm(csp, csp);
            var serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
            var urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
            var encoder = new JwtEncoder(algorithm, serializer, urlEncoder);

            return encoder;
        }



        public static RSAParameters ReadAsymmetricKeyParameter()


        {

\\ This key is fetched from the Service Account JSON File. 
\\"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<long-code>-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
\\ pick <long-code> from above. Replace all \n with actual new line like shown below.

                string pkey = @"MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQDSoGKK/Dzb8MBy
################################################################
################################################################
################################################################
################################################################
twySMqKKWnIC/zZljrvp4w==";



            RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters1;
            var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pkey);
            var asymmetricKeyParameter = PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(keyBytes);


            rsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters1 = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)asymmetricKeyParameter;

            RSAParameters r = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(rsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters1);

            return r;


        }
    }
}
```

Code Done in : .NET Framework 4.6.1

Nuget Packages :

[Bounty Castle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/) - Install-Package BouncyCastle -Version 1.8.6.1

Note : **Authorization Required on GCP**
Service account should have Data Catalog Viewer permission on all the projects, data catalog has to search for objects.

i.e. if Service Account is Created in project-id1, and search is required on both project-id1 & project-id2
It should have Data Catalog Viewer permission on both project-id1 & project-id2.

**This method can be used to call any GCP APIs by just changing the Request Body of actual API and providing required authority to Service Account**